# Fluid width (min width) sidebar, content occupies rest of width

Tags: html, css

I've searched and searched and only found implementations of FIXED WIDTH sidebars. I want a full-height sidebar that occupies minimum width. The table way of doing this would be

```
<table style='width:100%'>
  <tr>
    <td style='min-width:1px'>
      SIDEBAR CONTENT
    </td>
    <td>
      MAIN CONTENT
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But of course, tables-as-layout is increasingly frowned upon. With DIVs, I've tried floating the sidebar left, but I can't get it full height at that point. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this with css:

```
#div_id {width:10%;
         min-width:10px;
         height:100%;}
```

And positioning it as needed.

Comment: Does that refer to the sidebar element? I've tried a few variations: http://jsfiddle.net/1tLnec67/ and it doesn't seem to work as expected.